# How to properly catch runtime exception after losing internet connection

Tags: android, kotlin, try-catch, runtimeexception

I have a android map app that uses Mapbox APIs. Whenever I long press a location on the map, it returns a toast of the address of the map location I clicked. The app works fine but whenever the user clicks a location on the map while having no internet connection, the app crashes and returns a runtime exception.

I have implemented a try catch to handle the error, but it seems to fail and the same result still happens. I want to implement the try catch that whenever the error happens, the app will just return a toast saying that the user has no/slow internet.

Can anyone please help me implement this? Highly appreciated, thanks.

My code:

```
try {
                val annotationApi = mapView?.annotations
                val pointAnnotationManager =
                    annotationApi?.createPointAnnotationManager(mapView!!)

                binding.mapView.gestures.addOnMapLongClickListener() { point ->
                    // TODO - remove other location red_marker

                    val lat = point.latitude()
                    val lng = point.longitude()


                    pointAnnotationManager?.deleteAll()
                    val pointAnnotationOptions = PointAnnotationOptions()
                    bitmapFromDrawableRes(
                        this@PagePlanRouteMap,
                        R.drawable.red_marker
                    )?.let {

                        // Set options for the resulting symbol layer.
                        pointAnnotationOptions
                            // Define a geographic coordinate.
                            .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(lng, lat))
                            // Specify the bitmap you assigned to the point annotation
                            // The bitmap will be added to map style automatically.
                            .withIconImage(it)


                    }

                    userPickALocation = true
                    pointAnnotationManager?.create(pointAnnotationOptions) //CODE TO ADD PIN MARKER
                    val geoCoder = Geocoder(this@PagePlanRouteMap)
                    val address: List<Address> = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1)

                    val result = address[0].getAddressLine(0)

                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    etDestination.setText(result)

                    binding.searchResultContainer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                    true
                }
            }
            catch (e: RuntimeException){
                this@PagePlanRouteMap
                Toast.makeText(this,"No internet connection!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

Comment: add a if condition with internet available if its true than call this function else  return a toast simple no internet connect

Comment: I already tried doing this, but it still does not work, still returning the runtime exception